# How do you use shell I/O redirection to pass in arguments into Perl scripts?

Tags: perl, arguments, parameter-passing

Sorry if this is a really fundamental question to ask as I am quite new to Perl.

How would you add implement arguments into a Perl script using the I/O redirection symbols (`>` and `<`)?

e.g.

```
./program.pl file.txt
```

This would work with using `$ARGV[0]`, `$ARGV[1]` etc in the Perl script, but instead I want to use arguments passed in like this:

```
./program.pl < file.txt
```

Comment: Perhaps a little summary can be useful-- What is passed on the command line after the program name are _arguments_, available to the program in `@ARGV`.  But if you use the shell's redirection `<` then the program's `STDIN` is fed lines from the file whose name follows.  So then you must read `<STDIN>`. Instead, better read using the "magical" `<>`, which reads `STDIN` if opened (so it'll work with `prog.pl < file`), **or** it reads lines from all submitted files, so it will also work with `prog.pl file1 file2...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shell doesn't pass either `<` or `file.txt` to Perl when you run `./program.pl < file.txt`.  The content of the file can be read from standard input.  It's quite probable that you'd use:

```
while (<>)
{
    …
}
```

to process the input in the Perl script.  It will read each file name specified, or standard input if no names are specified.  There are tricks to detect when the file changes if you need them.

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't pass either `<` or `file.txt` to Perl. That tells the shell to redirect `perl`'s standard input.

To read from standard input, you use `STDIN`.

```
while (<STDIN>) {
   chomp;
   print "Got: $_\n";
}
```

However, that is very rarely done. Most of the time, you want to read from the special handle `ARGV` instead.

When you read from `ARGV`, all of the files named by the program's arguments (all those in `@ARGV`) are treated as one large file. If no argument were passed to the program  (`@ARGV` is empty), reading from `ARGV` reads from `STDIN` instead. This gives you the flexibility found in all well-designed unix tools (`cat`, `grep`, etc, etc, etc).

Say you have this program (`./a`):

```
while (<>) {   # Same as <ARGV>
   chomp;
   say "Got: $_";
}
```

```
$ ./a file1.txt file2.txt
Got: Line 1 from file1.txt
Got: Line 2 from file1.txt
Got: Line 1 from file2.txt
Got: Line 2 from file2.txt

$ ./a <file1.txt
Got: Line 1 from file1.txt
Got: Line 2 from file1.txt

$ grep -h 'Line 1' file1.txt file2.txt | ./a
Got: Line 1 from file1.txt
Got: Line 1 from file2.txt
```

Only the last two would work if you used `STDIN`.